# NativeScript UI Autocomplete don't compiled

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

In my nativescript app, I have a problem about using nativescript ui autocomplete. I compile my mobile application to android apps. It has an error as below

```
<======-------> 50% CONFIGURING [3s]
<====---------> 35% EXECUTING [13s]
<======-------> 51% EXECUTING [20s]
```

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class: com.telerik.widget.autocomplete.ShowSuggestionListListener
>   at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getClass(Generator.java:776)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.collectInterfaceMethods(Generator.java:703)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getPublicApi(Generator.java:227)und 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBinding(Generator.java:342)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBinding(Generator.java:133)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.processRows(Generator.java:172)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:90)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:66)
>           at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:47)
>   FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

```
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:runSbg'.
Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
BUILD FAILED in 25s
10:34:24 - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
Unable to apply changes on device: 192.168.80.101:5555. Error is: Command ./gradlew failed with exit code 1.
Executing after-watch hook from /home/andre/nativescript/TigaRoda/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-typescript.js
Stopping tsc watch
Executing after-watch hook from /home/andre/nativescript/TigaRoda/hooks/after-watch/nativescript-dev-webpack.js
Stopping webpack watch
```

Comment: Which version of {NS} and autocomplete are you using?

Comment: I'm using Nativescript 5.1.0

Comment: have you checked if nativescript-autocomplete version is latest ? also nativescript-autocomplete may be node_modules inside itself, try to delete that as well

Comment: what is the version of autocomplete and tns core modules?

Comment: Can you please check package-lock.json file and see which version of `nativescript-ui-autocomplete` is installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NativeScript tns build failed after adding nativescript-ui-dataform plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54511068/nativescript-tns-build-failed-after-adding-nativescript-ui-dataform-plugin)

Answer (score 2):

delete `node_modules`, `platforms`, `hooks` folders and `package-lock.json` file
run

```
npm i
```

rebuild the project ->

```
tns run android
```

or

```
tns build android
```