# NativeScript tns build failed after adding nativescript-ui-dataform plugin

Tags: android, angular, telerik, nativescript, nativescript-angular

I added plugin nativescript-ui-dataform to my project with command,

`tns plugin add nativescript-ui-dataform`

I checked package.json after install and noticed `"nativescript-ui-dataform": "^3.10.0"` was added to the project.

When I build project with `tns build android`, I get following exception,

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class:
com.telerik.widget.autocomplete.ShowSuggestionListListener
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getClass(Generator.java:776)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.collectInterfaceMethods(Generator.java:703)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.getPublicApi(Generator.java:227)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBinding(Generator.java:342)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBinding(Generator.java:133)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.processRows(Generator.java:172)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.generateBindings(Generator.java:90)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Generator.writeBindings(Generator.java:66)
        at org.nativescript.staticbindinggenerator.Main.main(Main.java:47)
```

and build failed with an error,

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

any suggestion on above error, why does this error occur?

Comment: `nativescript-ui-autocomplete` is a dependency for dataform plugin. Check your `package.lock.json` and see which version of autocomplete plugin is installed.

Comment: "nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "version": "3.11.0" @Manoj

Comment: Try `npm i nativescript-ui-dataform@3.9.1 nativescript-ui-autocomplete@3.10.3 --save`

Comment: @Manoj This solved the problem, but is there any problem with latest plugins `"nativescript-ui-dataform": "^3.10.0"` and `"nativescript-ui-autocomplete": "version": "3.11.0"`?

Comment: I'm not sure, these plugins are not open source and there is no specific guide that talks about internal dependency versions. My workaround is to refer the dependency list of Playground app unless I have time to go through the node modules to find the relevant dependency versions.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be the problem with using right dependent version for `nativescript-ui-autocomplete`. I'm sure the versions below are compatible to each other as it's being used in the latest Playground app as of today.

`npm i nativescript-ui-dataform@3.9.1 nativescript-ui-autocomplete@3.10.3 --save`